A world defined in propositional logic
The book Flatland describes what life would be like in a 2-dimensional world.
What would a world be like if it were only constructed in propositional logic, without quantifiers? What inherent structural or informational limitations would it have? Would time be possible in such a world?

2D geometry at least has expressive means to describe a surrogate "world" with 2D shapes. With propositional logic you only get truth tables. That's the "world", but there is no "life" in it.

What do you mean? Do you mean the book is fully written in propositional logic? The world itself is ontologically built from propositional logic? Please clarify
